# Starting and Stopping Ruby Daemons

Tags: ruby, daemons

I'm trying to start and stop an infinite loop daemon using the `daemons` gem.

Looking at the [home page](http://daemons.rubyforge.org), I tried (in irb):

```
require 'daemons'
=>true
task_handle = Daemons.call do
  loop{
    sleep 10
    puts "foo"
  }
end
=> #<Daemons::Application:0x000000043f96d0 ...
task_handle.stop
=> nil
task_handle2 = Daemons.call do
  loop{
    sleep 10
    puts "bar"
  }
end

=>Daemons::RuntimeException: there is already one or more instance(s) of the program running
from /home/bdares/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons/application_group.rb:125:in `new_application'
from /home/bdares/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/daemons-1.1.9/lib/daemons.rb:251:in `call'
from (irb):21
```

Now, the exact example (#3 on the linked page) I'm looking at makes the first call with the option `:multiple => true`, but I really only need one daemon to be running at a time (and multiple ones would, in fact, be undesirable).

Is the first daemon still somehow alive and not being GC'd?  If so, what am I missing?

Comment: Remember, A `Daemon` is just an abstraction over a UNIX daemon, which is just another UNIX process (usually created by `fork()` followed by `daemonize()`). So the GC doesn't really have any control whatsoever overanother UNIX process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding here is that *daemons do not run in order*. By the nature of them, they run in parallel with very little coordination between them. I'm sure you could find Ruby interfaces to System V IPC semaphores to coordinate them, but if you want a job queue, look at something besides Daemons.

Also, to add to @Sigurd's answer above, here's the code in question that implements the `:force` option (which is conveniently undocumented) ([source](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/classes/Daemons/ApplicationGroup.html#M000056)):

```
115: if @applications.size > 0 and not @multiple
116:         if options[:force]
117:           @applications.delete_if {|a|
118:             unless a.running?
119:               a.zap
120:               true
121:             end
122:           }
123:         end
124:         
125:         raise RuntimeException.new('there is already one or more instance(s) of the program running') unless @applications.empty?
126:       end
```

So basically, (`zap`, as I found in the source, does *absolutely nothing*), when you specify `:force`, Daemons will delete all non-running applications from `@applications` if multiple isn't set. Otherwise, you get an error. So what that means is that if you don't specify `:force` or `:multiple`, your on a one way street to errors.

Note: The reason for all of this is that `Application#stop` doesn't remove the Daemon from the `ApplicationGroup` (which is in charge of creating new jobs).

Note: By the way, it's bad form in Ruby to use `{}` for multiline blocks. Use `{}` only for single line blocks. Use `do...end` for multiline instead.

Answer (score 0):

The following code would work fine:

```
require 'daemons'
task_handle = Daemons.call(:force => true)  do
  loop{
    sleep 10
    puts "foo"
  }
end

task_handle.stop

task_handle2 = Daemons.call do
  loop{
    sleep 10
    puts "foo"
  }
end
```

The change is in a first call `:force` option. Daemons check app number that were created, not just that they are running. In your case, even after stop the first instance still exists. The "force" option cleans applications that are not running.

Please note that you may get another problem - `task_handle.stop` does not guarantee that the spawned proc would be stopped immediately, so you need to handle that situation.